# Algorithm to detect long and normal keyPressed event in java

Tags: java, events, keypress, 2d-games

I'm developing a little 2D game like Mario Bros, in this game when the user press the jump button depends of the milliseconds the jump button is pressed, Mario performs a small jump or a larger jump. 
I tried to declare a counter that increments into my keyPressed event but not working...

```
contadorSalto = 0;
contadorTiempoSalto = 0;


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

        int codigo = arg0.getKeyCode();
        if(codigo == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {           
            System.out.println(contadorTiempoSalto);
            contadorTiempoSalto++; 
            map.put("espacio", true);
        }
}
public void moverPersonaje(){
if(map.get("espacio")&&(contadorSalto < 1)){
      if(contadorTiempoSalto == 0){//less tant 1 second
          pj[0].setVelocidadY(-15);
      }
      if(contadorTiempoSalto > 0){
          pj[0].setVelocidadY(-25);
      }
      contadorSalto++;
  }
}
```

I can paste the rest of code if you want! Thanks

Comment: I would have all jumps be large jumps when the key is `pressed`, and have your descent from your jumps start after `x` seconds. If the key is `released` early, start your descent early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just recording that a key has been pressed in your map, record *when* the key has been pressed. Also add a keyReleased() handler that clears the key from the map.

You can then easily find out for how long the key has been pressed:

```
 public Map<Integer, Long> keyPressMap = new HashMap<>();

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    keyPressMap.put(arg0.getKeyCode(), System.currentTimeMillis());
 }

 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    keyPressMap.remove(arg0.getKeyCode());
 }

 // find out if key is pressed and how long it was
 Long t = keyPressMap.get(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
 if (t == null) {
     // not pressed
 } else {
     // pressed for X milliseconds
     long millis = t - System.currentTimeMillis();
 }
```

You can then decide what to do on how long the key has been down.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't rely on the keyPressed() and keyReleased() functions. Instead, use booleans that keep track of whether each key you care about is pressed, and set those booleans in the keyPressed() and keyReleased() functions.

Then in your game loop, check those booleans to determine which keys are currently pressed. Then either keep track of the number of frames a boolean is true, or record the system time when the boolean changes to get the elapsed time.